# Узнать, что указанный тип класса является наследником указанного интерфейса

Tags: c#

Добрый хэшкод, подскажи слепому!

Решил себя попробовать в написании аддонов к своему приложению. Для этого реализовал интерфейс с необходимыми для аддона функциями. Произвожу поиск в указанной папке dll, раскрывают в них все описанные типы через рефлекшин, проверяю, что указанный тип является не интерфейсом, однако встреча необходимый мне тип класса не знаю как проверить, является ли он наследником моего интерфейса. Глупо же создавать экземпляр класса и проверять, приводится ли он к указанному интерфейсу или нет.
В общем, уверен, что ответ на поверхности, но по какой-то причине я его не вижу.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Действительно слепой, дольше вопрос писал, чем было прочитать все методы типа.

    public virtual Type[] FindInterfaces(
     TypeFilter filter,
     object filterCriteria
    );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963160/how-to-determine-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-with-c-sharp-reflection

Comment: @pincher1519: может быть, вам не изобретать велосипед, а попробовать [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Это делается через метод [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: По логике -- да. По факту не сработает.

Comment: @Andrew почему вы так решили?

Comment: Потому что попробовал)
На коде в моем посте результат через даный метод неправильный.

Comment: @Andrew спорим, вы перепутали порядок параметров потому что поленились прочитать документацию? http://ideone.com/zsHxvt

Comment: какой смысл мне врать? http://prntscr.com/cqegz4

Comment: @Andrew так и есть, я угадал :) PS вы еще и по моей ссылке поленились перейти

Comment: Не поленился, я просто уже 24 часа не спал :) А метод и вправду рабочий. Прошу прощения

Answer (score 1):

Представим что есть интерфейсы/класы:

```
public interface IAnimal{}
public class Dog : IAnimal{}
public class Table{}
```

---

И проверка:

```
if(typeof(Table).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IAnimal)))
```

или

```
if(typeof(Table).GetInterfaces().Any(a=> a == typeof(IAnimal)))
```

Comment: а интерфейсы где?

Comment: Цитирую вопрос: *"Глупо же создавать экземпляр класса и проверять, приводится ли он к указанному интерфейсу или нет."* А вы что сделали?

Comment: Пофиксил, забирай минуса :)